# F# Casting Operators

Tags: casting, f#, type-conversion

What is the difference between the following F# casting operators? I can't seem to understand why and how they are all different.

```
(type) X
X :> type
X :?> type
```

Comment: This only covers Upcast and Downcast.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The first isn't a cast in F#, though if you're used to C# it might appear that it works like one.  But this is actually invoking a type conversion *function* (like `int`), and the parentheses aren't actually required (and are just likely to make everything more confusing).

```
(int) "4" // the number 4 - this is a conversion, not a cast
int "4"   // same thing, but idiomatic
int "NaN" // compiles but throws an exception at runtime
(int) (box 4) // doesn't compile because int doesn't do downcasts, just known conversions
```

Note that this works for primitive types, because there are predefined conversion functions, but it won't work for arbitrary types:

```
(bigint) 1 // no such conversion function, so this is a compile-time error
```

The difference between the other two is that `:>` performs upcasts (from a type to a supertype, which is always safe) and `:?>` performs downcasts (from a type to a subtype, which might fail, thus the `'?'` in the middle).

There are also named `upcast` and `downcast` operators which can be used in a similar way:

```
5 :> obj                 // upcast int to obj
(upcast 5 : obj)         // same
(box 5) :?> int          // downcast an obj to int (successfully)
(downcast (box 5) : int) // same
(box "5") :?> int        // downcast an obj to int (unsuccessfully)
```

In some contexts the target type of the upcast or downcast may be successfully inferred, in which case you don't need the type annotations when using the `upcast` or `downcast` operators, while you always need to provide a type argument to the `:>` or `:?>` operators (though you can supply `_` if you expect it to be inferred):

```
List.map (fun x -> x + 1) (downcast (box [1]))
List.map (fun x -> x + 1) (box [1] :?> _)
```

Comment: Those feel like the other way around from logic (I always get confused by the subtype arrow :/). They are, right? Guess it's a grammar limitation.

Comment: Is there anything that can cast a, lets say, `obj` to something that has a certain operator available, like `*`?  I know you can make a generic constraint to do that by having a fairly complex looking bit of code `<'T when 'T : (static member (+) : ^T * ^T -> ^T)>`, but is there a way to cast it to that?

Comment: @DanRayson - no, but you can use standard .NET reflection to call such a method without needing to perform a cast.