# What does the :> operator do in F#?

Tags: f#, operators

What does the `:>` operator do in F#?

e.g.

```
myFunction x :> System.Object
```

Comment: What question do you have that is not answered by the first google result for `f# :> operator`?

Comment: I have never looked at F# before and I found the answer in less than a minute.... how long did it take to write this question I wonder?

Comment: I only searched StackOverflow. Now there are two ways to find the answer.

Comment: If this is a duplicate it should be closed otherwise I think it it's a relevant newbie question.

Comment: @FuleSnabel possible dupe target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616761/f-casting-operators

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It converts a type to type that is higher in the hierarchy. So it's a conversion operator.

See the following example (take from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd233220.aspx) and the previous definition too) :

```
type Base1() =
    abstract member F : unit -> unit
    default u.F() =
     printfn "F Base1"

type Derived1() =
    inherit Base1()
    override u.F() =
      printfn "F Derived1"


let d1 : Derived1 = Derived1()

// Upcast to Base1.
let base1 = d1 :> Base1
```

Answer (score 4):

Converts a type to type that is higher in the hierarchy.
Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx

--
Like casting an Entity type to Player type.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the reference. The F# language reference is excellent and should a natural place for both newbies and experienced developers to search for questions like these.